# DartPad Not Supporting ON Clause

Tags: dart

I'm learning **Dart Language** by working with dart code in **DartPad.**
While using **on clause** in Exception it throws uncaught exception.

[image: Screenshot of DartPad Error]

Comment: That was added to Dart only very recently. It's likely DartPad needs an update. Please create an issue in https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues

Comment: This use of `on` is not new, it's been there for years. It's only the `mixin` declaration which is new.

Comment: You are right of course. Didn't even look at the code because the screenshot was shown too small on my phone and I assumed it's about mixins.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that dart2js, which DartPad is based on, does not throw an `IntegerDivisionByZeroException` (which should really be named `DivisionByZeroError`, but alas, isn't) when you do integer division by zero.
It throws, but it's using `UnsupportedError` instead, which is otherwise a good choice for such an error.

Dart2js is *not wrong*. Neither the language specification, nor the library documentation for `num.~/` says that it should throw that particular error type. Still, it's inconsistent with the other compilers, so we may want to make it consisent.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try replacing the error received with IntegerDivisionByZeroException with the error found i.e,

```
void main(){
  try {
    int result = 12 ~/ 0;
    print (result);
  } on UnsupportedError { print("hua solve"); } 
  finally { print("cool!"); }     
}
```